# How to make a van follow the road's L/R tilt

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, camera, constraints

I have a van model with a *Follow Path* constraint, so that it moves following a curve. The curve itself was first shrinkwrapped on the road below, so that it follows its shape. Lastly, a camera is parented to the van, so that it moves together with it, creating an animation.

Everything works as intended, except for one thing: the van+camera doesn't tilt/rock left or right when the road is inclined perpendicularly with respect to the direction of movement. Just to be clear, the van+camera does correctly follow the road uphill and downhill.

[image]
Here you see the van+camera rig just before the beginning of a sloped road that would require the van to "rock" L/R, with the right part above the left one, and the camera tilted accordingly as well.

How can I achieve the effect I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

you have to check "follow curve" and (!) you have to tilt your curve manually - the shrinkwrap doesn't do that for you - unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Follow curve" is already enabled, and it makes the van correctly curve together with the road. Can you tell me more on how to tilt the curve manually? if it can be done manually, maybe it can also be somehow "automated" on the basis of the road below?

Comment: Sorry, I have seen now there's a "tilt" slider when selecting the curve in edit mode that does what I want. But, again, if it can be done manually, maybe it can also be made to follow the road below? Any suggestions? Thanks again!